# PHP gets wrong file name

Tags: php

I am simply trying to display an image with a number in the file name (the member ID).  However, the server tends to take the image with the same numbers in the file name, re-arranged, if that makes sense (like the ascii value).

```
<div id="memPicBox">
    <div id="memImage">
    <?php 
        $memPic="mp".$clientId.".jpg";
        echo "<span style='color:white;'>$memPic</span>";
    ?>
    <img src="pics/members/<?php echo $memPic ?>">
    </div>
    <div id="loadPicButton">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

    </div>

</div>
```

So, member ID 630 shows the image file of member 603, even if there is no file for member ID 630.  Member ID 603 shows the image for ID 603.

In other words, all site members have an ID, and there image file name is "mp"+memberID+extension.  Member 603's image shows up in member's 630 image box! Even if member ID 630 has no file ("mp630.jpg")  And, this is true for other members with the same digits in the ID's.

I hope this makes sense, because it is driving me senseless.

Here is .htaccess:

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
     order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from all
 </Limit>
 <Limit PUT DELETE>
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
 </Limit>
 AuthName usapa.htpickleball.org
 AuthUserFile /homepages/31/d93584081/htdocs/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
 AuthGroupFile /homepages/31/d93584081/htdocs/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

If I were to look in to the browser's source code view it shows "mp630.jpg" for the image src. And, it previews the image for mp603.jpg.  There is no "mp630.jpg" file, at all.

By the way, this does not happen on localhost, only on the server (1and1).

Comment: I believe the code you posted should not produce the effect you describe. Have you tried echo'ing out `$clientId` to see if the value is wrong? `var_dump($clientId); die;`

Comment: Sounds like some rewriting issue to me.

Comment: Yes, the file name is correct in the echo (mp630.jpg). But ID 630 shows the pic for 603 (mp603.jpg)

Comment: a) When you open the source code view in your browser what's the value of the `src` attribute? b) just for debugging purposes try `<img src="pics/members/<?php echo $memPic . '?'.time()?>" alt="<?php echo date('H:i:s d-m-Y'); ?>">` and check the date value in the browser's source code view.

Comment: I added the answers to questions above in the main question area.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: Could you please copy&paste the source for the complete img tag (including the time and date in the alt attribute) as seen in the brower's source view to a comment here?

Comment: VOLKERK = When I added your <img> with the time and date, this fixed the issue!  Why is that????  Here is the copy/paste: <img src="pics/members/mp630.jpg?1446378607" alt="04:50:07 01-11-2015">

Comment: Most likely a "problem" with the browser cache. Appending the time was supposed to force the browser to re-reload the contents and the alt tag to confirm that you're really looking at the output of the "latest and greatest" version of your php script.

Comment: I love you, dearly!  You are some kind of genius.  Thanks!  Oooh, I am so impressed.

Comment: But keep in mind that this "fix" is probably not a "solution". You now know that you can run into cache-problems with your 1&1 server. You might want to look into that topic. Just appending the timestamp would force the browser to request the image data every single time you request that page - even if the cache _could_ serve the images. see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en for starters....

Comment: Wait!  For some reason it resolved 630 > 603; 603 > 630, but 150 > 510 is still confusing the file names! Ahhh. God, why would it resolve one ID but not the other?

Comment: I added a scan_dir to check if the file exists along with the info from your link, and resolved the issue.  You're great!